# Complex find and replace in notepad++

Tags: search, replace, find, notepad++

I'm trying to do a find and replace in notepad++ where i remove the dashes from a set of numbers and letters formatted as following: aa-aaa-nn-nnnnn
I've considered writing a plugin, but it just seems like too much work to be worth it.

Here's an example of what I have and what I need.
I have this: `<ISRC>AB-CED-12-34567</ISRC>`
And the result should be: `<ISRC>ABCED1234567</ISRC>`
I've tried finding `(A-Z+)-(A-Z+)-(\d+)-(\d+)` and replacing this with `\1\2\3\4`
but then it can't find the "text". If I knew how to write the darned search codes, I could do this myself, but I just can't find a complete guide anywhere.

Comment: Just replace `-` with (nothing). Also, learn about "Regular expressions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, you want to use [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `([A-Z]+)-([A-Z]+)-(\d+)-(\d+)`
- Replace with: `$1$2$3$4`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

`[A-]+` means one or more uppercase letter, if you want to match also lowercase, use `[A-Za-z]+`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot! And thanks from my colleague who needed this.